# Ruby "#<NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass>"

Tags: ruby, indexing, syntax, null

I have the following code which looks for the letters "u"and "e" in a word and add 1 to the index so that it shows position in the word starting from 1 rather than 0, and then have it combined into an array.

```
def vowel_indices(word)
  x = (word.index("u") + 1)  
  y = (word.index("e") + 1) 
  print = [x,y]
end
```

I am getting the following error message when running:

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass>
```

What is nil in this? From what I can see my variables are assigned correctly.

Comment: What is the value of `word`?

Comment: The word I am testing with is "super". However, there is no value stored in variable word.

Comment: When I run your code with `vowel_indices("super")` it works fine. The error is elsewhere. How are you calling the method?

Comment: If `word` does not contain a `"u"`,  `word.index("u") + 1 #=> nil + 1`, raising the exception you got, since `nil` does not have a method `:+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because for some values assigned as `word` may not contain a `u` or `e`.

If you are using Rails, then you can overcome this by modifying your code like this:

```
def vowel_indices(word)
  x = (word.try(:index, "u").try(:+, 1)  
  y = (word.try(:index, "e").try(:+, 1) 
  print = [x,y]
end
```

In this way, you can prevent the method trying to call `:+` method for if the class is [Nil](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/NilClass.html).

In instances which we are not sure about the input, it's better to use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks for pointing that out. My mistake, I thought he use Rails. I have modified my answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 1):

"What is nil in this?"

As @ Cary Swoveland and @Lahiru already said, if a word is passed in that doesn't have a 'u' or 'e' that exception will be raised:

```
001 > def vowel_indices(word)
002?>     x = (word.index("u") + 1)  #word.index("u") returns nil if the word arg passed in doesn't have a 'u' 
003?>     y = (word.index("e") + 1) 
004?>     print = [x,y]        #I've never seen the 'print =' syntax...any reason you're not just returning [x,y] here?
005?>   end
 => :vowel_indices 
006 > vowel_indices("cruel")
 => [3, 4] 
007 > vowel_indices("cat")
NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):2:in `vowel_indices' # This tells you exactly where the exception is coming from
    from (irb):7
    from /Users/kenenitz/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Two quick & dirty ways to handle this would be to either add a conditional to check for the presence of each letter, or you can rescue `NoMethodError`:

```
#conditional check (preferred as it is more precise)
def vowel_indices(word)
  u_index = word.index("u")
  e_index = word.index("e")
  x = u_index ? u_index + 1 : nil #verify that u_index is not nil before calling :+ method
  y = e_index ? e_index + 1 : nil # same for e_index

  [x,y]
end

#rescuing NoMethodError, not preferred in this case but including as a possible solution just so that you're familiar w/ this approach

def vowel_indices(word)
  begin
    x = word.index("u") + 1
    y = word.index("e") + 1
  rescue NoMethodError
    x = nil
    y = nil
  end
  [x,y]
end
```

With either solution I provide, if a word is missing a 'u' or 'e', the return value would contain `nil` which would most likely require some sort of special handling elsewhere in your program:

```
vowel_indices("cat")
 => [nil, nil] 

vowel_indices("cut")
 => [2, nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = "Hello" # example

def vowel_indices(word)
  x = (word.index("u") + 1) # x = (nil + 1) *There is no "u" in "Hello"
  y = (word.index("e") + 1) # y = (1 + 1) *Output as expected based on index
  print = [x,y]
end

p word.index("u") # will return nil if you need to check the return value
```